# What is the difference between convex cone and convex hull?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-geometry

I am reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone) definition of convex cone and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) definition of the convex hull of a finite set of points and I am in trouble in understanding the difference.

Am I right that, given a set of points $x_1,..., x_n$ in $R^m$, convex cone is defined by

$$y \in R^m | y=\sum a_i x_i, a_i \geq 0, i=1,...,n  $$

and convex hull same than above but with

$\sum a_i=1$ in supplement ?

Thanks for clarification. A "geometric" example on a 2D dataset would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The two are very different in definition. Definitions:

> A set $S\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a convex cone if, for any $x\in S$ and any positive real $\alpha$, the vector $\alpha x$ is also an element of $S$. That is, $S$ is a convex cone if and only if $$\forall x\in S\forall \alpha\in[0,\infty):\alpha x\in S$$
>
> For a set $X$, the *convex hull* of $X$ is the smallest convex set that contains $X$.

You can see a very big difference in the two definitions in the fact that a convex hull is defined *in terms of another set*, while "convex cone" is a property that a set can either have or not.

That is, it is possible to take a set, $S$, and ask "is $S$ a convex cone?". This question has a yes or no question, depending on $S$. On the other hand, the question "is $S$ a convex hull" doesn't have a yes or no question. You have to change the question to "Is $S$ a convex hull of $X$" before you can answer it.

Comment: The OP is clearly asking about the notion of a convex cone *induced* by a particular set, i.e., the smallest convex cone containing the set. Your answer does not address this. Also, your definition of convex cone is incomplete because it does not mention that a convex cone has to be convex.

Comment: @JessRiedel If you think my answer is not what the OP wanted, it's a much better idea to add your own (better) answer than just complain about my answer.

Comment: @JessRiedel Also, neither of the two definitions the OP cites is about "a convex cone *induced* by a particular set". So I don't know how you can claim with such certainty that *that* is what the OP is asking, let alone how you can claim that this is what they are **clearly** asking. Now, you might be right. and you might be wrong. I don't know. The only one that can *with certainty* claim that my answer is useful or not is the OP, and they chose to say nothing for over a year, so the question doesn't really interest me anymore.

Comment: I stand by the content and usefulness of my criticism, but I should have made the tone of my comment friendlier. Sorry about that.